# Setting query params to an array is not working

Tags: ember.js

How do I set a query param to an array?

I have the following setup:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['sort'],
  sort: null,

  actions: {

    onSortChanged(sort) {
      console.log('Sorting By: ', sort); // sort = ['name:asc']
      this.set('sort', sort);
    }

  }

});
```

But it renders as `?sort=name%3Aasc` whereby I need it to render as `?sort[]=name%3Aasc`.

or for example if it had two items, `?sort[]=name%3Aasc&sort[]=age%3Adesc`

I should also mention that if I pass the array `?sort=name%3Aasc` in the url manually it works. Only when the query string is changed in code that this behaviour occurs.  I tried using `this.transitionTo(this.routeName, {queryParams: {['sort:asc']}})` from the route but I get the same issue.

Comment: I have had similar issues in the past. Can you try updating the code such that your definition of sort is an empty array on line 3. i.e. `sort: Ember.A()`.

Comment: Well it is now working using your suggestion.  The query string is rendered like this `?sort=%5B"isNew%3Aasc"%2C"name%3Adesc"%5D` which translates to `?sort=["isNew:asc","name:desc"]`.  So it has actually rendered the array into a single sort parameter which is kind of weird.  I would have expected `sort[]=isNew%3Aasc&sort[]=name%3Adesc`.  I always thought that was convention for arrays in the query string but maybe there is none.